# IBOutletCollection doesn't show up in interface builder in Xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, xcode6, iboutlet, iboutletcollection

In my appdelegate.h I have a pretty humble IBOutletCollection of NSViews as such:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(NSView) NSArray *views;
```

However whenever I go to my mainmenu.xib, the Outlet Collections sublist is nowhere to be found on the App Delegate object's connections. Dragging views to the app delegate doesn't bring up the outlet either, even though the outlet circle beside the line numbers inside the editor is visible at that line.

Is anyone else experiencing this problem? This is in beta 5 with objective-c.

Comment: It's not a "binding", it's a connection.

Comment: @matt my bad, I always get the two mixed up. Just to confirm, I meant to say I was looking in the connections tab (the draggable outlets tab)